# How to map a string to a table column in MS Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access, mapping, case, string-matching

I need an SQL query to map the string content of a column in TableA to a set of columns in TableB. It looks like this:

```
TableA
| ID | Status |
---------------
| 0  | "full" |
| 1  | "part" |
|    |        |

TableB
| ID | full | part |expire|
--------------------------
| 0  | true | false| false|
| 1  | false| true | false|
|    |      |      |      |
```

I am using MS Access and currently this is all I've got:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.ID = TableB.ID
```

Which correctly matches the two tables based on ID. However, I do not know where to go from here. Lets say the following is added to TableA:

```
{ID:2, Status:"Expire"}
```

How can I map this from TableA to TableB? Ideally this would all be done in 1 query.

Many thanks in advance! :)

Comment: What is the expected result? it's better to share if you share it with us.

Comment: Its hard to understand what you want.. give us a sample of desired output.

Comment: TableB is an example of the desired output after querying TableA. I left the third row blank purposely so that running the query again would add ID#2 to TableB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`IIf()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IIf-Function-32436ecf-c629-48a3-9900-647539c764e3) function for each column.

```
SELECT ID,
    IIf([Status]='full', True, False) AS [full],
    IIf([Status]='part', True, False) AS [part],
    IIf([Status]='expire', True, False) AS [expire]
FROM Table1
```

Comment: How would I incorporate this into an UPDATE SET? Could I just use SET instead of SELECT?

Comment: `SET [full] = IIf([Status]='full', True, False)` should work.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear enough.

If you want to recreate TableB from TableA then use the **IIf ( expr , truepart , falsepart )** function in a query.
Example below (added status field - you can exclude it):

```
Select ID,Status, IIf([Status]="full", true, false) as full, IIf([Status]="part", true, false) as part,IIf([Status]="expire", true, false) as expire from TableA
```

If you meant to join the two tables then use LEFT OUTER join that will include all rows in TableA. In this case row 3 will have nulls for the boolean flag since there is no matching row.

```
SELECT TableA.ID,Status,full,part,expire FROM TableA LEFT JOIN TableB ON TableA.ID = TableB.ID
```

Regards,
Bikxs